# Flash not surviving a redirect in Facebook on a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, facebook

I have the following two action methods:

```
def index
  puts "==index== flash: #{flash.inspect}"
end

def create
  flash[:notice] = "Blah"
  puts "==create== flash: #{flash.inspect}"
  redirect_to(:action => :index)
end
```

index.fbml.erb contains this:

```
<%= button_to_with_facebooker "Blah!", :action => :create %>
```

The application is used through Facebook. I click the button and the flash contains the notice while create is being executed, but after that it's empty again. It doesn't survive a redirect. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Seems to be a bug somewhere. More information on http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/browse_thread/thread/db62cdab0171bc6d/e48d5c036ddc35c4?lnk=gst&q=flash#e48d5c036ddc35c4 and http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/browse_thread/thread/cb7e27cb3095cca7/ed62a4345487d59f?lnk=gst&q=flash#ed62a4345487d59f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one workaround. While using ActiveRecord to store the session, add

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.delete Rack::FacebookSession
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.insert_before(
  ActionController::Base.session_store,
  Rack::FacebookSession,
  ActionController::Base.session_options[:key])
```

in an initialization file, like config/initializers/session_store_fix_facebooker_session_key.rb

[This has been done on by someone else before](http://github.com/thhermansen/bruktmarked/commit/97db26d610ce99add5a7d7665c3440c5d72fe152) and [he explained it on a message on the Facebooker group](http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/msg/410aa04cd183c92e) on but [it doesn't work with the cookie session storage, Rail's default](http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/msg/38d23216ec8cb765).